# How can I add a new column to a csv/sqlite based on today's date?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, beautifulsoup

I feel like I'm approaching this the wrong way. I want to use BeautifulSoup to read some URLs from a CSV, then grab the latest prices for a price scraper and write them to a different csv.

Ideally, I want to read and write to the same database. Could be sqlite or MySQL.

In my URLs file, I have:

```
SKU | URL
```

In the results, I want to append a "price" column with today's date as the column header name.

The CSV should be:

```
SKU | URL | October 6 Price | October 7 Price | October 8 Price
```

This is clearly the wrong way to go, as I'm not using some key to write the prices back.

```
import datetime
import urllib2
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def price_scrape():
    data = []
    datadict = {}
    with open("master_urls.csv") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        with open("current_prices.csv", 'w') as r:
            writer = csv.writer(r)
            for row in reader:
                ulkey = row['URL']
                page = urlopen(ulkey)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
                # get the name
                name_box = soup.find('h1', attrs={'class': 'heading product-view__title'})
                name = name_box.text.strip()
                # get the price
                price_box = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'price'})
                price = price_box.text.strip()
                sku_box = soup.find('td', attrs={'data-th': 'Model Number'})
                sku = sku_box.text.strip()
                now = datetime.now()
                todaysdate = now.date()
                data.append((name,price))
                writer.writerow([name, sku, price, todaysdate,row['URL']])
```

What should be the correct way of approaching this? Should I be writing to a dictionary, then to SQlite?

Comment: I'm a little confused about what your goal is.   At the end of everything, do you want to create a new CSV file with the updated prices?  Or do you want the data stored in a database?

Comment: flat file format is preference for database load meaning a distinct column for sku, url, date and one for price. I would be appending row wise not column wise. You don't want to have to keep altering table schema and imagine what a nightmare selecting from that table would be.

Comment: @ChrisCurvey, I want to know what would be more efficient. It would be to do everything in a database right?